# How to install Oracle thin jdbc drivers on ubuntu

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g, ubuntu-12.04

I have downloaded the .jar files of drivers from this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html

But now, I'm not sure what to do with these .jar files. How do I install them?

Comment: where do you want to use this driver?

Comment: A JDBC driver does not need to be "installed". Just copy it somewhere convenient and include it in your Java project.

Comment: you mean include it in my source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar files for the oracle jdbc driver should be installed with your program. If you are running your application on an application server such as tomcat, or jboss you should follow the instructions in the application server manual on how to install a jdbc driver into the application server.  If you are creating a command line application create put the files in \lib folder as part of your app and it to you applications classpath.

Please clarify your question are running within app server or not? If within an app server which one?

You can learn more about the concept of the classpath and you will understand exactly what to do. Start here  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to the classpath. It's usually only needed at runtime.

Comment: where is the classpath in linux. Plz clarify new to java on linux